# UIview Demo rotate only in one direction

Tags: ios, xcode, rotation, direction

I am working with this sample code [RotationPie](https://github.com/wczekalski/CDPieMenu). It is a wheel, and I want to move it or rotate it in my project ONLY in one direction. I want to put different options and the user will have to choose one of them. I wanted the wheel only to rotate in one direction. I think that I have to change something in this method in the class CDCircleGestureRecognizer but I don´t know what.

```
- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
   if ([self state] == UIGestureRecognizerStatePossible) {
      [self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateBegan];
   } else {
      [self setState:UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged];
   }

   // We can look at any touch object since we know we 
   // have only 1. If there were more than 1 then 
   // touchesBegan:withEvent: would have failed the recognizer.
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

   // To rotate with one finger, we simulate a second finger.
   // The second figure is on the opposite side of the virtual
   // circle that represents the rotation gesture.

    CDCircle *view = (CDCircle *) [self view];
   CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX([view bounds]), CGRectGetMidY([view bounds]));
   CGPoint currentTouchPoint = [touch locationInView:view];
   CGPoint previousTouchPoint = [touch previousLocationInView:view];
    previousTouchDate = [NSDate date];
    CGFloat angleInRadians = atan2f(currentTouchPoint.y - center.y, currentTouchPoint.x - center.x) - atan2f(previousTouchPoint.y - center.y, previousTouchPoint.x - center.x);

    CGFloat one = atan2f(currentTouchPoint.y - center.y, currentTouchPoint.x - center.x); 

     CGFloat two =atan2f(previousTouchPoint.y - center.y, previousTouchPoint.x - center.x);    
    currentTransformAngle = atan2f(view.transform.b, view.transform.a);


   [self setRotation:angleInRadians];
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should store the current angleInRadians in a variable, and allow the rotation only if the new angle is greater (or lesser) than the current one.

Comment: But this value change, sometines when you rotate to the right is positive, sometines negative... I could not understand it